# How to store objects in Android Room?

Tags: android, android-room

Basically, there are two things I don't understand: objects with objects and objects with lists of objects

Say I receive a list of objects from the server. Each of them looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class BigObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;
    private User user;
    private List<SmallObject> smallObjects;
}
```

with these two objects as fields:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;
    private String name;
    @TypeConverters(GenderConverter.class)
    public MyEnums.Gender gender;
}

@Entity
public class SmallObject {
    @PrimaryKey (autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;
    private String smallValue;
}
```

They are more complicated than this, so I can't use @TypeConverters as Room suggests:

```
error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.
```

How do I store this data structure in Room?

Comment: In general, entities do not hold other entities in Room, either individually or as lists. They might hold *foreign keys* to other entities. And other structures, like a view model, can hold whatever entities are needed. So, `BigObject` needs to get rid of `smallObjects` and replace `user` with `userId` as a foreign key. `User` and `SmallObject` would have foreign keys back to `BigObject`. Then, set up a view model or something that you populate from `@Query` DAO methods that retrieves the `BigObject`, its related `User`, and its related `SmallObjects`.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I think the best way to answer this is a breif overview in storing structures...

**Lists**

Room does not support storing lists that are nested inside of a POJO. The recommended way to store lists is to use the foreign key approach. Store the List of objects in a seperate table (in this case a smallObjects table) with a foreign key to their related parent object (in this case "big_object_id"). It should look something like this...

```
@Entity
public class BigObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;
    private User user;
    @Ignore
    private List<SmallObject> smallObjects;
}

@Entity(foreignKeys = {
            @ForeignKey(
                entity = BigObject.class,
                parentColumns = "id",
                childColumns = "big_object_fk"
            )})
public class SmallObject {
    @PrimaryKey (autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;
    private String smallValue;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "big_object_fk")
    private int bigObjectIdFk
}
```

Note that we have added the `@Ignore` annotaiton to `List<SmallObject>` as we want to ignore the field during Room persistance (as lists are not supported). It now exists so that when we request our list of related small objects from the DB we can still store them in the POJO.

To my knowledge this will mean you are making two queries.

```
BigObject b = db.BigObjectDao.findById(bOId);
List<SmallObject> s = db.smallObjectDao.findAllSOforBO(bOId);
b.setsmallObjects(s);
```

It appears that there is a short hand for this in the form of [@Relation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Relation.html)

**Type Converters**

These are for cases where you have a complex data structure that can be flattend without losing information, and stored in a single column. A good example of this is the Date object. A Date object is complex and holds a lot of values, so storing it in the database is tricky. We use a type converter to extract the milli representation of a date object and store that. We then convert the millis to a date object on the way out thus keeping our data intact.

**Embedded**

This is used when you want to take the fields of all nested POJOs in your parent POJO and flatten them out to store in one table. an example :

```
- name
- age
- location
    - x 
    - y
- DOB
```

..when embedded this structure would be stored in the database as :

```
- name 
- age 
- location_x
- location_y
- DOB
```

In a sense Embedded exists to save you time creating type converters for every nested object that contains primary type fields like String, int, float, etc...

Comment: Embedded docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Embedded.html

Comment: @Jack Dalton Will the ForeignKey approach insert the data into appropriate table from the service response?

Answer (score 4):

## Convert Object/`List<Object>` to String and then, Store it.

You can store the objects in Room Library as String. For that, you can serialize the object and store it as String in the Room Database.

**Store to Room**

> Object -> Serialize -> String -> Store

**Read from Room**

> > String -> Deserialize ->Object -> Read

### How to Serialize/Deserialize?

There are many options available. You can either do it manually or you can use a library for this. You can use Google's [GSON library](https://github.com/google/gson). It is pretty easy to use.

> Code: Object -> String

```
public String stringFromObject(List<YourClass> list){

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonString = gson.toJson(list);
    return jsonString;

}
```

> Code: String-> Object

```
public List<YourClass> getObjectFromString(String jsonString){

    Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<YourClass>>(){}.getType();
    List<YourClass> list = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, listType);
    return list;

}
```

Comment: Where do you serialize from.

Comment: From the Java Object. ie Object------>String @GilbertS

Comment: Didn't work out. I used @Relation. It allows you to access the associated list

Comment: @Relation? What does it mean?

Comment: I think the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Relation) will explain better

Comment: This approach solves the issue of storing a JSON representation as a record in Room. However, what this will not do for you is be able to easily query or filter by an attribute by accessing Room itself. The only way I can this is possible if all instances of the Entity were converted from string to object and then an in-memory query against all of those objects is performed.

Comment: I agree 100% with @MarkLapasa. If your requirement is to search, filter. Use multiple tables, make relations with tables using foreign keys. But remember, rverything has a tradeoff!!!