# How to store object type in Room (java Android)

Tags: java, android, android-room

i want to store a Object type in Room database.

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "control")
private Object control;
```

This object is to store widgets like, TextViews, Buttons, .... but, i had this error :

> Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.

How can i solve it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44736604/how-to-store-objects-in-android-room

Comment: I guess type convertor will help you to store this object into string and will return you in object form when needed.

Comment: the solution on the link, works fine. thanks @SMA

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a provision of saving Views in Room. The Room Database can be used to store the **data that you will be displaying or not displaying in the views**.

What you can do is

1. Store a series of boolean values and info .
2. Depending on the boolean value display or don't display the view and populate accordingly with the data stored in room